# Find pattern and replace string between (regexp_replace or substr)

Tags: regex, oracle, dynamic, substr

Friends,

I'm trying to generate dynamic sql script and replace string from the original query result.

```
Original: '/u02/DB/FILE/file01.dbf' or 
Original: '+DATA/DB/FILE/file01.dbf'

Required : '/u01/data/dbname/file01.dbf'
```

1. Start search from 2nd character from original, find 1st and 2nd appearance of '/' and replace with data (hopefully this covers both original scenario)
2. Start search from 2nd character from original, find 2nd and 3rd appearance of '/' and replace with dbname

DB and FILE in original could be any location so can't really hardcode that.

I use below to replace FILE with dbname but that's not helping totally,

Somehow feels approach is too complex and there should be better/diferent way.

```
    SELECT 'alter database rename file ''' || f.file_name || ''' to '''|| '/u01' ||
          REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(f.file_name, INSTR(f.file_name, '/',2)), '/FILE/', '/dbname/', 1||''';' stmt
    FROM ( SELECT name file_name, bytes
             FROM v$tempfile
             ORDER BY bytes ESC
         )f;
```

Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: Try something [like `regexp_replace('/u02/DB/FILE/file01.dbf', '^([^/]*/[^/]*/)[^/]*/[^/]*', '\1data/dbname')`](http://rextester.com/DEX39226).

Comment: WOW, that was super quick, looks like it's working as expected, will test completely and confirm.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked perfectly, how can we edit it slightly to search from 2nd character to avoid +DATA?

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting that: you should just use `^` to match the start of string, then `[^/]*` to match 0+ chars other than `/` and then `/` - that will be the first `/`, then add `[^/]*` to get to the 2nd `/`.

Comment: Sorry if I was not able to explain it properly, provided solution works if string starts with '/' but if original starts with +DATA then we don't get correct result. so trying to start search of '/' from 2nd character of the original string.

Comment: It seems you just need to change the first `*` into `+` (at least one occurrence): `^([^/]+/[^/]*/)[^/]*/[^/]*` - you may consider changing all `*` to `+` if you do not plan to match strings with `//` in them.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a single regex replace operation with:

```
^([^/]*/[^/]*/)[^/]*/[^/]*
```

Replace with `\1data/dbname`.

**Details**

- `^` - match start of a string
- `([^/]*/[^/]*/)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern):

  - `[^/]*` - 0+ chars other than `/`
  - `/` - a slash
  - `[^/]*` - 0+ chars other than `/`
  - `/` - a slash
- `[^/]*` - 0+ chars other than `/`
- `/`   - a slash
- `[^/]*` - 0+ chars other than `/`

A [quick online test](http://rextester.com/DEX39226):

```
select regexp_replace('/u02/DB/FILE/file01.dbf', '^([^/]*/[^/]*/)[^/]*/[^/]*', '\1data/dbname') AS RESULT from dual
```